# Python - request exceptions variable timeout

Tags: python, exception

While using requests module in python with the following code

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://somerandomurl.com', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
```

I get this error

```
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I specify a variable timeout by which the request will be repeated if it timed out? 
Python is new to me.

Comment: Fix your indentation

Comment: No, it isn't. If that's how your code is indented that's isn't correct.

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the code. if this is wrong can you provide an example of correct indentation?

Comment: Code works fine for me (somerandomurl.com is actually a blog so I got a 200 :-)). My guess is you are missing a closing bracket of some kind on  a previous line.

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code for this function/method?

Comment: You should paste more code around the `try ... except`

Comment: If you have a new question please post a new question. Do not edit this one to be a new question.

Comment: @ArushiChopra your indentation is wrong after `try:` there should be  `new line and tab` that's why the incorrect syntax error was thrown  fixed the indentation see now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you.

```
try:
    res = requests.get(adress,timeout=30)
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print("OOPS!! Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to Internet. Technical Details given below.\n")
    print(str(e))            
except requests.Timeout as e:
    print("OOPS!! Timeout Error")
    print(str(e))
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("OOPS!! General Error")
    print(str(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Someone closed the program")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you could add timeout as a param to the request. In the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts) you can read:

> **Timeouts**
>
> You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given
>   number of seconds with the timeout parameter:
>
> ```
> requests.get('http://github.com', timeout=0.001)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> requests.exceptions.Timeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=80): Request timed out. (timeout=0.001)
> ```

**However** I don't think that will solve your problem. As the error (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`) and some of the comments suggest there is probably something wrong with your code in some earlier stage which is not included in your example-code.

Regarding **indentation**: Indentation is a big political thing in all programming languages. In most languages its strictly cosmetical and has no other use than to make the code readable. But in python the indentation has semantical meaning witch makes it important how its done. As long as you are consistent with the indentation you use (in your case 2 spaces) it is syntactically correct but most python-programmers tend to (rightfully so) abide to the [Style Guide for Python Code (pep8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which states that indentation should be done with *4 spaces per indentation level*.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and its working

```
>>> try:
...     r = requests.get('http://somerandomurl.com', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
... except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
...     print "exception"
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: @IanAuld i said i tried this and found it working :p first check my response then comment

Comment: Saying "works fine for me" does not answer the OP's question nor will it help any future readers. The problem is most likely on a previous line.

Comment: @IanAuld I simply copied code which was shared above and tried it , found it working .... so i wrote its working ...nything wrong

Comment: can I change the timeout to something of my choice?

Comment: @ArushiChopra ur choice like please explain ?   or you can also do except Exception: raise YourChoiceException

Comment: can i set Timeout to 5 seconds?

Comment: @ArushiChopra for timeout you can set timeout in requests.get example:requests.get(url, timeout=5)